# What is the physical interpretation of K-Mean cluster membership?

Tags: interpretation, k-means

I understand clustering as an optimization problem for a given set of points finding k centers minimizing the maximum distance. Using as an example a k-means algorithm for 2 features only (x=quality, y=costs). What is the physical interpretation of the membership respectively the distance in the cluster? Many thanks for your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I suppose you could impose a physical analogy, K-means doesn't have much of a physical interpretation. It does look for a partition of a collection of points such that the average distances are minimized, but these are not necessarily to be interpreted as physical distances. Informally speaking, things that are close together are grouped together.

In mathematics a 'distance' is more formally called a "[metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics))", and it is just a type of function that holds certain abstract properties. Namely that a metric on a set $X$ is a function $d: X \times X \mapsto [0,\infty)$ (i.e. into the non-negative real numbers) such that for $\forall x,y,z \in X$ the following hold:
$$d(x,y) = 0 \iff x = y$$
$$d(x,y) = d(y,x)$$
$$d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$$

Comment: I would add to @Galen's great answer that membership in a cluster can be interpreted as observational units which have predictor features that are varying degrees of similar, depending on the radial distance of the cluster

Comment: Thanks Galen. I understand that's a metric and not a physical distance. But what have members of a certain cluster in common repectively is the "underlying pattern", if in terms of quality and costs, the member with the distance based on quality=10/cost=1 is similiar to quality=1/cost=10 ?

Comment: @Sepp I'm not sure what you mean by "underlying pattern". Two members of a given cluster were closer to each other in their quality and cost than they were to others outside the cluster.

Comment: @Galen Sorry for being not clear. In this example 10/1 & 1/10 you could have 2 members with complete different characteristics for quality and costs (patterns) in the same cluster.

Comment: @Sepp Yes, you can have distinct points that are symmetric {(a,b) vs (b,a)} within a single cluster.

Comment: @ Galen Asking as an engineer, what is then the practical use or insight of a cluster in such a case, when physical or business metrics could completely be reverse, but appear in the same cluster ?

Comment: @Sepp Clusters are sometimes, but not always, meaningful. You're partitioning the points based on how close they are to each other, but that 'closeness' is not always informative for the data analyst.